# Quicksight Countover with Conditional

Tags: count, amazon-quicksight

I have a table with order information. It is broken down by OrderID, Item Name. How can I get the count of all orders with multiple x and y items. For example, how many orders have more than 1 dumplings and more than 1 water?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Countif function like:

```
countIf (
    Revenue,
    # Conditions
        CalendarDay >= ${BasePeriodStartDate} AND 
        CalendarDay <= ${BasePeriodEndDate} AND 
        SourcingType <> 'Indirect'
)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/countIf-function.html)